# is there a way to iterate over constant used as enum

Tags: go, enums

I am trying to use enum in golang as below. I am struggling to find a easy way to iterate over the list of constant values. What are common practice in golang to iterate over constant values used as enum. Thanks!

```
type DayOfWeek int
const(
       Monday DayOfWeek = iota
       Tuesday
       Wednesday
       Thursday
       Friday
       Saturday
       Sunday
      )
```

In Java, we can iterate as below.

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY, 
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY
}

for (DayOfWeek day: DayOfWeek.values()) {
   // code logic
}
```

Comment: First, all Go identifiers are normally in [MixedCaps](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#mixed-caps), including constants. You could either do a simple loop such as `for d := Monday; d <= Sunday; d++ {}` where you explicitly know the start/end values or you could add aliases for those (e.g. something like `firstDay = Monday; lastDay = Sunday`). Although it's possible to go further to make something that would use `range` IMO it's absolutely not worth it.

Comment: By the way, there already is [`time.Weekday`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday) that goes from `time.Sunday` to `time.Saturday`. (Of course you just happened to put days of the week as an arbitrary example this is unimportant).

Comment: Dave, Thank you for your response. I corrected the case for the constants. I am looking enums in general not just the weekday. firstDay and lastDay seems interesting to me. Should that go in the const lists or they are outside variables? Thanks!

Comment: @DaveC: your comment would be fine as an answer

Comment: For enums that I need to be iterable, I usually add a dummy end marker. Taking the example of days of the week, my code would have loops like `for i := Monday; i < LastDay; i++ {`. That way, if hell freezes over and I need to add an 8th day to the week, I just have to shove it before `LastDay`, the dummy end marker. This is a common pattern in languages that do not have builtin support for iterating over enums, like C, Go, etc.

Comment: @wldsvc that would be a super answer. Too bad this is so old.

Comment: I'm new to all of this, so shoot it down at will.  Could one have the last entry be "sizeOfDayOfWeek", and then create a slice `DayOfWeek[:sizeOfDayOfWeek]` for use with `range`?  This is my 3rd day of `go`, so be kind.  This is sort of a retread of @wldsvc's comment.

Answer (score 28):

There is no direct way to enumerate the values/instances of named type at runtime, whether variables or constants, unless you specifically define a slice that lists them. This is left up to the definer or the user of the enumeration type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var Weekdays = []time.Weekday{
    time.Sunday,
    time.Monday,
    time.Tuesday,
    time.Wednesday,
    time.Thursday,
    time.Friday,
    time.Saturday,
}

func main() {
    for _, day := range Weekdays {
            fmt.Println(day)
    }
}
```

In order be able to generate this list dynamically at runtime, e.g. via reflection, the linker would have to retain all the symbols defined in all packages, like Java does. The golang-nuts group discussed this, regarding names and functions exported from a package, a superset of package constant definitions. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/M0ORoEU115o

It would be possible for the language to include syntactic sugar for generating this list at compile time if and only if it were referenced by the program. What should the iteration order be, though? If your week starts on Monday the list I defined is not very helpful; you will have to define your own slice to range through the days from Monday to Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without reflection.

First execute the Go tools `Stringer` at compile time using `go generate`. This creates a file `[filename]_string.go` which contains a map `_[structname]_map` of enum values referencing enum variable names as strings. This map is private, so simply assign it to a public map upon package initialization.

```
var EnumMap map[Enum]string

func init() {
    EnumMap = _Enum_map
}

type Enum uint

//go:generate go run golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer -type=Enum

const (
    One Enum = iota
    Two
)
```

Then you can simply loop over the keys of the map.

Comment: Great idea but sadly, when I try this the generated code doesn't build a map.  Apparently that happens only if there are 10 or more "runs" (sets of consecutive values")

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @davec was great. This works perfect when you have a count that increments by one.

```
You could either do a simple loop such as for d := Monday; d <= Sunday; d++ {}
```

I had constant that jumped in bits (1,2,4,8,16 etc):

```
const (
    Approved = 1 << iota
    AlreadyApproved
    NotApproved
    OldTicket
    Unknown
)
```

I avoided `range` and did a left shift one to move through my constant:

```
var score Bits
score = Set(score, AlreadyApproved)

for i := Approved; i < Unknown; i = i << 1 {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringer` is preferable it can help you keep your codebase up to date using code generators. Unfortunately `stringer` does not always generate the map.

For anyone interested in keep using go generators for this purpose I wrote a small code generator called `enumall`. It produces a file for each provided type with variable holding all values for given type.

Use it by adding code generator comment to your code like this:

```golang
//go:generate go run github.com/tomaspavlic/enumall@latest -type=Season

type Season uint8

const (
    Spring Season = 1 << iota
    Summer
    Autumn
    Winter
)
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/tomaspavlic/enumall

Answer (score 0):

```
for i := 0; i <= int(Sunday); i++ {
    fmt.Println(DayOfWeek(i))
}
```